# Getting the newest filename in a directory in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible script, and I am trying to get the filename of the newest item in a directory.  I am using this Ansible script:

```
- name: Finding newest file in a folder
  find:
    paths: "/var/www/html/wwwroot/somefolder/"
    age: "latest"
    age_stamp: mtime
```

However, I am getting the following error -

```
FAILED! => {"age": "latest", "changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "failed to process age"}
```

How can I get Ansible to retrieve the filename of the newest file in a directory?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Pure Ansible solution:

```
- name: Get files in a folder
  find:
    paths: "/var/www/html/wwwroot/somefolder/"
  register: found_files

- name: Get latest file
  set_fact:
    latest_file: "{{ found_files.files | sort(attribute='mtime',reverse=true) | first }}"
```

Comment:   pure and beautiful

Comment: The last line is prettier like this: `latest_file: "{{ found_files.files | sort(attribute='mtime') | last }}"`

Comment: The solution from @Def_Os is really clean as well. (:

Comment: The suggestion by @Def_Os makes the solution much clearer.

Comment: NB: To get the file path as a result, use ```latest_file: "{{ (found_files.files|sort(attribute='mtime')|last).path }}"
``` Else you get a dict as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Using a system command:

```
- name: List letencrypt certificate directory
  command: ls -t1 /etc/letsencrypt/live/
  register: certificates

- set_fact: latest_certificate="{{ certificates.stdout_lines[0] }}"
```

This saves the latest directory generated by certbot.