# How to find new files in a directory and divide/split file name with the version name at the filename?

Tags: ansible

I have a directory that contains files like `der_azureData_Linux_x64_24.1.0.0.7.tar`. I need to find out the latest file in that directory and split the file name into name and version.

**Expected output**

```yaml
name: der_azureData_Linux_x64
version: 24.1.0.0.7
```

**Playbook**

I tried with the below playbook but it is not displaying the file name.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
      - find:
          paths: "/root/ansible.temp/"
          patterns: "*.tar"
          recurse: yes
        register: files_matched

      - set_fact:
          latest_files: "{{ latest_files | default([])  + [item.path] }}"
        loop: "{{ files_matched.files | sort(attribute='mtime', reverse=true) }}"
        when: "item.path | dirname not in latest_files | default([]) | map('dirname')"
        ## 
        # The loop_control is just there for validation purpose
        ##
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime(item.mtime) }} {{ item.path }}"

      - debug:
          var: latest_files

      - name: check the directories and locations
        shell: |
            f = {{ latest_files }} # loop over each file in current directory
            name="${f%_*}"         # trim from right to first '_'
        register: name

      - name: print values
        debug:
          msg: "filename {{ name.stdout }} "
```

**Output as follow**

```
TASK [check the directories and locations] **************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [print values] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "filename "
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Your shell task define a variable but does not output it. Hence your `stdout` being empty is totally expected. Moreover, doing this with a shell task is a bad practice. Use `regex_replace` and/or `split` and/or `map` .... directly in a jinja2 expression, something like (totally untested) `my_files: "{{ latest_files | map('regex_replace', '^.*-(.*)$', '\\1') }}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to find new files in a directory? ... I need to find out the latest file in that directory.*

Given the test files

```bash
tree test
test
├── newest.yml
├── test_1.2.3.4.tar
└── test_2.3.4.5.tar

ls -al test*
-rw-r--r--. 1 user users   0 Jan 16 12:00 test_1.2.3.4.tar
-rw-r--r--. 1 user users   0 Jan 16 12:00 test_2.3.4.5.tar
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get files in a folder
    find:
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test"
      patterns: "*.tar"
    register: result

  - name: Get newest file
    set_fact:
      LATEST: "{{ result.files | sort(attribute='mtime',reverse=true) | first }}"

  - name: Show LATEST
    debug:
      msg: "{{ LATEST.path | basename }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show LATEST] ****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test_2.3.4.5.tar
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Getting the newest filename in a directory in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974094/6771046)

---

> *How to divide or split file name with the version name at the filename?*

You may then proceed further with

```yaml
  - name: Show VERSION only
    debug:
      msg: "{{ LATEST.path | basename | split('_') | last | splitext | first }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show VERSION only] ****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 2.3.4.5
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Extract file names without extension - Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61931335/6771046)

---

**Filters Used**

- `basename`
- `first`
- `last`
- `split`
- `splitext`

**Further Documentation**

- [Using filters to manipulate data - Managing file names and path names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)