# How to get a file with the highest version number from a list of files in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a scripts directory on my Ansible Control Node.

In this directory there are multiple files, `Worker1_0`, `Worker1_5`, `Worker2_1` and so on. The numbers are version numbers.

I want to write a role which automatically finds those files in the directory and passes the file with the highest version number to the Ansible script module.

I am finding the files like that:

```yaml
- name: Find Worker
  find:
    paths: "{{ scripts_path }}"
    patterns: "Worker*"
    file_type: file
  register: worker
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

Which gives me a list of all the files.

I then tried to put them into a list like so:

```yaml
- name: Show Output
  debug:
    msg: {{ worker | json_query('files[*].path') | sort | reverse }}
```

which seems to do the sorting, but I am still not sure if my approach is correct. This is the output:

```json
ok: [SERVER] => {
    "msg": [
        "/srv/git/scripts/Worker3_8",
        "/srv/git/scripts/Worker3_5"
    ]
}
```

As final step I want to pass only the file with the highest version number to Ansible script module, but I cant get it to work.

I tried it like that:

```yaml
- name: Execute Script on Remote server
  ansible.builtin.script:
    cmd: "{{ item }} "
  with_first_found: "{{ worker | json_query('files[*].path') | sort | reverse }}"
  register: script_output
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I get this error message:

```json
FAILED! => {"msg": "No file was found when using first_found."}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the goal of a sorted list of versions, a specific sort algorithm and therefore filter is necessary. A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    worker_list:
      - "/srv/git/scripts/Worker2_1"
      - "/srv/git/scripts/Worker1_5"
      - "/srv/git/scripts/Worker1_0"
      - "/srv/git/scripts/Worker3_8"
      - "/srv/git/scripts/Worker3_5"

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ worker_list | community.general.version_sort }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ worker_list | community.general.version_sort | last | basename }}"
    # Better do Data Reduction, reduce data before processing it 
    #      "{{ worker_list | map('basename') | community.general.version_sort | last }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - /srv/git/scripts/Worker1_0
  - /srv/git/scripts/Worker1_5
  - /srv/git/scripts/Worker2_1
  - /srv/git/scripts/Worker3_5
  - /srv/git/scripts/Worker3_8

TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Worker3_8
```

**Similar Q&A and Dcoumentation**

- [How to sort version numbers in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75307333/6771046)
- [How to ... divide/split file name with the version name at the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75133688/6771046)
- [Working with versions - `version_sort` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_working_with_versions.html)