# Sort a list of strings that contain numbers in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is there a way to properly sort this list of virtual machine names? Azure and Ansible reports them as follows:

```
dev-xxx-myvm-1
dev-xxx-myvm-10
dev-xxx-myvm-2
dev-xxx-myvm-3
dev-xxx-myvm-4
dev-xxx-myvm-5
dev-xxx-myvm-6
dev-xxx-myvm-7
dev-xxx-myvm-8
dev-xxx-myvm-9
```

RESULT:

```
dev-xxx-myvm-1
dev-xxx-myvm-2
dev-xxx-myvm-3
dev-xxx-myvm-4
dev-xxx-myvm-5
dev-xxx-myvm-6
dev-xxx-myvm-7
dev-xxx-myvm-8
dev-xxx-myvm-9
dev-xxx-myvm-10
[...]
```

Comment: Sure, since that question comes up frequently, see [How to get a file with the highest version number from a list of files in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77537901/6771046) and use `"{{ YOUR_LIST | community.general.version_sort }}"`

Comment: Where are those names coming from? A file? A dynamic inventory plugin? Something else?

Comment: those come from azurerm.virtualmachine_info

Comment: @U88D this is part of a larger list of dictionaries variable, where those are actually the values of the name key. i don't think this plugin can sort dictionaries or accept sort attributes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest solution is to use `community.general.version_sort`.

```
- name: "Getting deployment state"
  block:
  - name: "Getting deployment state"
    azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info:
      resource_group: myRG
    register: existing_vms
  - name: Saving all VM names in vm_names
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      vm_names: "{{ vm_names | default([]) + [item.name] }}"
    loop: "{{ existing_vms.vms }}"
  - name: Sorting the VM names in vm_names_sorted
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      vm_names_sorted: "{{ vm_names | community.general.version_sort }}"
```

Comment: Couldn't you have used one `set_fact`? `vm_names: "{{ (vm_names | default([]) + [item.name]) | community.general.version_sort }}"`