# I want to print a specific line/value in my stdout using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

In my playbook, I run the gitlab-rake backup command works as expected. Now I want to print the output for this example its "1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5_gitlab_backup.tar" but I'm struggling to find a way on how to print this.

here's my playbook:

```
tasks:
     - name: GitLab rake backup
       become: yes
       shell: "gitlab-backup create SKIP=repositories,db,uploads"
       register: gitlab_backup

     - debug: "msg={{gitlab_backup.stdout | regex_search ('Creating backup archive:'.'*') }}"
```

this is the output when the backup completed:

```
TASK [GitLab rake backup] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [cdopla-538.bell.corp.bce.ca] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "gitlab-backup create SKIP=repositories,db,uploads", "delta": "0:03:30.216704", "end": "2024-01-29 19:34:13.442518", "msg": "", "rc": 0, "start": "2024-01-29 19:30:43.225814", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping database ... [SKIPPED]\n2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping repositories ... [SKIPPED]\n2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping uploads ... [SKIPPED]\n2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping builds ... \n2024-01-29 19:31:22 -0500 -- Dumping builds ... done\n2024-01-29 19:31:22 -0500 -- Dumping artifacts ... \n2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping artifacts ... done\n2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping pages ... \n2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping pages ... done\n2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping lfs objects ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping lfs objects ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping terraform states ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping terraform states ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping container registry images ... [DISABLED]\n2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping packages ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Dumping packages ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Dumping ci secure files ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Dumping ci secure files ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Creating backup archive: 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5_gitlab_backup.tar ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Creating backup archive: 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5_gitlab_backup.tar ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Uploading backup archive to remote storage  ... [SKIPPED]\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting old backups ... [SKIPPED]\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting tar staging files ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/backup_information.yml\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/builds.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/artifacts.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/pages.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/lfs.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/terraform_state.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/packages.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/ci_secure_files.tar.gz\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting tar staging files ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting backups/tmp ... \n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting backups/tmp ... done\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Warning: Your gitlab.rb and gitlab-secrets.json files contain sensitive data \nand are not included in this backup. You will need these files to restore a backup.\nPlease back them up manually.\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Backup 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5 is done.\n2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting backup and restore PID file ... done", "stdout_lines": ["2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping database ... [SKIPPED]", "2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping repositories ... [SKIPPED]", "2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping uploads ... [SKIPPED]", "2024-01-29 19:31:19 -0500 -- Dumping builds ... ", "2024-01-29 19:31:22 -0500 -- Dumping builds ... done", "2024-01-29 19:31:22 -0500 -- Dumping artifacts ... ", "2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping artifacts ... done", "2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping pages ... ", "2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping pages ... done", "2024-01-29 19:33:34 -0500 -- Dumping lfs objects ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping lfs objects ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping terraform states ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping terraform states ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping container registry images ... [DISABLED]", "2024-01-29 19:34:04 -0500 -- Dumping packages ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Dumping packages ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Dumping ci secure files ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Dumping ci secure files ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:05 -0500 -- Creating backup archive: 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5_gitlab_backup.tar ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Creating backup archive: 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5_gitlab_backup.tar ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Uploading backup archive to remote storage  ... [SKIPPED]", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting old backups ... [SKIPPED]", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting tar staging files ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/backup_information.yml", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/builds.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/artifacts.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/pages.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/lfs.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/terraform_state.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/packages.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Cleaning up /app/gitlab/backups/ci_secure_files.tar.gz", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting tar staging files ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting backups/tmp ... ", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting backups/tmp ... done", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Warning: Your gitlab.rb and gitlab-secrets.json files contain sensitive data ", "and are not included in this backup. You will need these files to restore a backup.", "Please back them up manually.", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Backup 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5 is done.", "2024-01-29 19:34:13 -0500 -- Deleting backup and restore PID file ... done"]}
```

I only need to print this file name: 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5
Anyone can help

I only need to print this file name in my stdout: 1706574679_2024_01_29_16.4.5
Anyone can help

Comment: Maybe it would be sufficient to just get the newest file in the directory containing the backup? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974094/1417694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution 1:

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: backup_name
    vars:
      backup_name: "{{ gitlab_backup.stdout | regex_search('Creating backup archive:\\s(.*?)\\s','\\1') | join('') }}"
```

here we use `gitlab_backup` which you are registering from your backup task and using regex we search for pattern and match just the part which is backup file name. and in the end we `join` the values. here join is used to just convert output of regex_search to string since output type is list.

solution 2:
if You are not good with regex(which regex in solution 1 is really simple) you can use this one. it feels more like filtering with tr/grep/cut in shell:

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: bak_name
    vars:
      bak_name: "{{ gitlab_backup.stdout_lines | select('match', '.*Creating backup archive.*done') | join('') | split(' ') | select('match','^\\d+_.*') }}"
```

- select line which match our pattern (`grep`)
- convert to string from list
- split(`tr ' ' '\n'`)
- match the line which starts with number and has underscore after numbers(`grep '^[0-9]*_'`)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fixed it using below:

set_fact:
gitlab_name: "{{ gitlab_backup | regex_findall(tar) | first }}"
vars:
tar: "[0-9]{10}*[0-9]{4}*[0-9]{2}*[0-9]{2}*[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+_gitlab_backup.tar"

Thank you, @Yanser! I was also able to get the idea